# MvxBindableLinearLayout ItemsSource binding issue

Tags: android, binding, android-linearlayout, mvvmcross

I'm having trouble designing a Activity.

I'm trying to use a Mvx.MvxBindableLinearLayout, making bind to a list: A, B and c;

When I do this binding, the result is:
A
B
C
C
B
A

The correct would be:
A
B
C

The code in question is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/m2uMobileSales.Droid"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     >

  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/m2uMobileSales.Droid"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:showDividers="none"
      android:layout_weight="1">

    <include
        layout="@layout/PageCommon_Titlebar" />

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:stretchColumns="1">
      <TableRow
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
          android:stretchColumns="1">
        <!--Customer Name-->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/CustomerName"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            local:MvxBind="{'Text':{'Path':'Customer.CustDetails.Name','Mode':'OneWay'}}" />
      </TableRow>

      <TableRow>
        <!--Detail Pages android:padding="12dp" -->

        <Mvx.MvxBindableLinearLayout
             android:padding="3dip"
             android:id="@+id/ClienteDetails"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:divider="@null"
              android:dividerHeight="0dp"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
              android:layout_weight="1"
              local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/listitem_clientdetailpages"
              local:MvxBind="{'ItemsSource':{'Path':'DetailPageViewModels'}}"/>

        <!--<Mvx.MvxBindableListView
            android:id="@+id/ClienteDetails"
            android:divider="@null"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/listitem_clientdetailpages"
            local:MvxBind="{'ItemsSource':{'Path':'DetailPageViewModels', 'Mode':'OneWay'}}" />-->
      </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>

  </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

If I use commented Mvx.MvxBindableListView, I can only see the first item.
The objective is scroll all the elements and not the list, doing as the definitions of android.
After overcoming this problem, I will have a list within a list (DetailPageViewModels will have several elements including a list).

I've seen several posts that advise inserting all elements inside a ScrollView.

I tried comment Mvx.MvxBindableLinearLayout, ScrollView and MvxBindableListView worked well. If I use ScrollView I only see the first element.

My objective is use MvxBindableLinearLayout, because I need scroll the entire page, and and non elements.

listitem_clientdetailpages code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/m2uMobileSales.Droid"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:showDividers="none"
    android:layout_weight="1">

  <!--Page Title-->
  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/detailpagetitle"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:textSize="24dp"
       android:padding="3dip"
      local:MvxBind="{'Text':{'Path':'Title','Mode':'OneWay'}}" >
  </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

I apologize for the confusion.

Thanks for the help and availability.

Comment: update added - please try reproducing your problem in an existing sample - e.g. in the main menu of the tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a coworker of Paulo Dias and we've just figured out what's happening...
The problem is in the creation of the `MvxBindableLinearLayout`

In the constructor we have

```
 Adapter = new MvxBindableListAdapterWithChangedEvent(context);
 Adapter.DataSetChanged += AdapterOnDataSetChanged;
```

And in the 'Set' of the property 'Adapter' we have

```
var existing = _adapter;
if (existing == value)
    return;

if (existing != null && value != null)
{
    existing.DataSetChanged -= AdapterOnDataSetChanged;
    value.ItemsSource = existing.ItemsSource;
    value.ItemTemplateId = existing.ItemTemplateId;
}

if (value != null)
{
    value.DataSetChanged += AdapterOnDataSetChanged;
}
```

The first time the Adapter is created, the `DataSetChanged` event is subscribed two times (in the constructor and in the set of the adapter property).
This can be a problem if we have a notifiable collection binded to the `MvxBindableLinearLayout`.

Now the tricky part... This bug only 'reveals himself' when we do changes in the binded list **after** the ui control is created (i.e. add new items to the list). If we have a list in the viewmodel that is 'setted in the constructor' and then is never changed, the `DataSetChanged` event will never be fired. On the other hand, if we add items after the ui is created (i.e. you can have a command binded to a button, that adds items to the list), the items will be duplicated in the ui...

To solve this, we´ve just commented the line in the `MvxBindableLinearLayout` contructor where the DataSetChanged` is beeing subscribed, and all falls back to place :)

```
        public MvxBindableLinearLayout(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs)
            : base(context, attrs)
        {
            var itemTemplateId = MvxBindableListViewHelpers.ReadAttributeValue(context, attrs,
                                                                               MvxAndroidBindingResource.Instance
                                                                                                        .BindableListViewStylableGroupId,
                                                                               MvxAndroidBindingResource.Instance
                                                                                                        .BindableListItemTemplateId);
            Adapter = new MvxBindableListAdapterWithChangedEvent(context);
            Adapter.ItemTemplateId = itemTemplateId;
            //Adapter.DataSetChanged += AdapterOnDataSetChanged;
            this.ChildViewRemoved += OnChildViewRemoved;
        }
```

Hope this can help!

ps: Wondering why anyone didn't had this problem before...

ps1: We are currently using MvvmCross vNext.

ps2: I've changed to Mvvmcross V3, and the problem persists. I'll make a request in Github

Answer (score 2):

I just tried in v3 and this code worked as expected:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.cirrious.dailydilbert"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  >
   <Mvx.MvxLinearLayout
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       local:MvxBind="ItemsSource Items;ItemClick ItemSelectedCommand"
       local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/listitem_dilbert" />
</ScrollView>
```

I can't really see any problems in the LinearLayout for the code you've posted. It might help if I could see the template for the list item, and the viewmodel list itself. If you think there's a bug, then please post a simple reproduction somewhere and I'll look at it - the more full that reproduction the quicker I can look at it - i.e. ideally post a full solution on a github repo - I can just download and run it then.

For the bindable ListView I'd be a bit suspicious of the attribute `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` - suspect that might not work properly.

---

Update, I also tried in the Tutorial app, replacing the ListView with a LinearLayout in `Page_MainMenuView.axml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/Tutorial.UI.Droid"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  >  
<Mvx.MvxLinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    local:MvxBind="ItemsSource Items;ItemClick ShowItemCommand"
    local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/listitem_viewmodel"
  />
</ScrollView>
```

This displays perfectly - does this work also in your setup?

If it does, then the problem must be somewhere in the code you're not including...

Comment: I commented all the code to do the same. The difereça is that I use the Mvx.MvxBindableLinearLayout. My template only contains a LinearLayout and a TextView. I do nothing in code. In windows phone 8 everything works fine.

Comment: Sorry - I don't understand that last comment

Comment: we are using vnext. I'm too confused to understand the cause of the problem.

Comment: please go back to the tutorial app - does the main menu there work? See if you can change that app one line at a time to get the same problem - or to make it work.

Comment: I tested using a Mvx.MvxBindableLinearLayout inside a scrollview in another activity and it worked. Mode Mvx.MvxBindableLinearLayout load equals other controls? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Sorry - not sure I understand again... does that mean the problem is solved? If so :) If not, then please try saying more - maybe even try 'not English' - try in Portuguese?

Comment: My problem remains unresolved. But you were right and the code worked in another case (other activity).

Comment: OK - so now it's up to you to spot the differences.