# adding an object to an ObservableCollection makes two UI items appear

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I made a simple test app where I have a MvxLinearLayout with ItemSource bound to an ObservableCollection of string values. The item template is a TextView.

On a Button I add a new string to the collection. In the UI there are two items added.

I am using latest MVVMCross from NuGet, and running under Debug with Linker set to 'Don't Link'

I uploaded the source code of the app here:
http://sdrv.ms/13l9dnR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the same behaviour happen if you use an MVxListView?

- If it doesn't, then it sounds like you've hit a bug in the linearlayout binding - in which case the best place to log that is: https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/issues/new - or you can try to solve the error yourself - https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/v3/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid/Views/MvxLinearLayout.cs
- If it does, then I suspect there is a bug in your logic somewhere.

Comment: thank you Stuart. With MVxListView it adds one item only. I will fill the bug.

Answer (score 1):

This issue was allready posted and solved in stackoverflow:
[MvxBindableLinearLayout ItemsSource binding issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15932400/mvxbindablelinearlayout-itemssource-binding-issue/15969479#15969479)

My bad for not filling a bug in GitHub... I apologize for that.
I can reply on thew new bug, after you create it.

This particular issue is due to a subscription of a the same event twice (all is explained in the link above).

Once again, sorry for not posting the bug in GitHub. Won't happen again